# System not waking up after suspend with Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, 18.10

I'm running 18.10 on my Precission 5530 with Nvidia Quadro P2000. 
My system does not wake up from suspend when using the Nvidia card. I read that this seems to be a common issue but could not find a fix.
At the moment I am using driver version 418.56 but I had the same problems with all other drivers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The driver version is adequate. You may need additional boot parameters and/or tweak the power saving profile.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but not sure which one and how to set them. Might it also be possible to use the newest version 430?